# How do I get my images to appear in my HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

The HTML and CSS below together creates a blue page with 5 black diamond boxes. The next step is to make those black boxes into images. The problem is the first image will not appear properly. The location/url is correct and exist as I put it as an image before the div to test.

I believe the issues lies with

```
ul.gens li.gen1 .image {
    background: url(staticfiles/images/fire.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

But every edit or test I do shows no results of the image appearing. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the HTML segment so you can see my classes:

```
<body class="generations">

    <!-- Diamond Shape Grid -->

    <ul class="gens">
        <li class="gen1">
            <div class="image"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="gen2">
            <div class="image"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="gen3">
            <div class="image"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="gen4">
            <div class="image"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="gen5">
            <div class="image"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</body>
```

Here is the CSS for this page. It sits with my other page's css. Everything works for this page specifically with their tags.

```
/* Generation styles */

body.generations {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #2c2c54;
}

ul.gens {
    position: absolute;
    width: 600px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

ul.gens li {
    list-style: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: black;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    margin: -100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul.gens li.gen1 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

ul.gens li.gen2 {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 25%;
}

ul.gens li.gen3 {
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
}

ul.gens li.gen4 {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 75%;
}

ul.gens li.gen5 {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

ul.gens li .image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.42);
}

ul.gens li.gen1 .image {
    background: url(staticfiles/images/fire.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Your code is fine so it is probably do do with the path in your url. Is `staticfiles` a subfolder of the folder your CSS is in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it appears to be working when you substitute a different url in place: https://jsfiddle.net/1j4rwsvc/2/

So it looks like your url path is incorrect! try `url: ('./staticfiles/images/fire.jpg');`

Comment: I have checked that 100 times... does it need quotes as it's in a directory like it would in <img src="pic.png">?

Comment: @Genoxidus any change you can add a screenshot of your file structure to from where that html page is to where the image is?

Comment: I follow what is the recommend practive as seen here, when it comes to the '' in the url definition: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: https://imgur.com/q8oyMCY
Tried to change the path and retyped everything etc.

Comment: You need to exit out of your css file first using `../` so something like the following `url: ('../staticfiles/images/fire.jpg');`

Comment: oh my... I'm so dumb... I'm thinking I need to route it from the html file and not the css... wow me... thank you!!!!